# What's a clean way to allow a block to handle a variable number of arguments?

Tags: ruby, block, proc

I've run into this situation before, and something tells me the way I generally handle it is not the cleanest or most idiomatic.

Suppose I have a function that takes a block, which can in turn take 1 or 2 (say) parameters.

```
def with_arguments(&block)
  case block.arity
  when 1
    block.call("foo")
  when 2
    block.call("foo", "bar")
  end
end

with_arguments do |x|
  puts "Here's the argument I was given: #{x}"
end

with_arguments do |x, y|
  puts "Here are the arguments I was given: #{x}, #{y}"
end
```

Switching on `arity` seems pretty hacky. Is there a more standard Ruby way to achieve this kind of thing?

Comment: Can't you split the method into something like `with_one_argument` and `with_two_arguments` (of course they would not really be called that)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I'd pass arbitrary arguments to a `lambda`:

```
def with_arguments(&block)
  args = %w(foo bar)
  n = block.arity
  block.call *(n < 0 ? args : args.take(n))
end

with_arguments &lambda { |foo| }
with_arguments &lambda { |foo, bar| }
with_arguments &lambda { |*args| }
with_arguments &lambda { |foo, *args| }
with_arguments &lambda { |foo, bar, *args| }
```

If `n` is negative, then the `lambda` takes an arbitrary number of arguments. Precisely `(n + 1).abs` of these arguments are mandatory. One can use that information to decide which arguments to pass.

If the `lambda` takes a finite number of arguments, then just pass the first `n` elements of `args`. If it takes an arbitrary number of arguments, then just pass the entire argument array.

The `lambda` itself will handle the cases where `args` is insufficient:

```
with_arguments &lambda { |foo, bar, baz, *args| }
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)
```

---

You can simply pass the two arguments to the block:

```
def with_arguments(&block)
  block.call 'foo', 'bar'
end

with_arguments { |x| puts x }              # y is not used
with_arguments { |x, y| puts x, y }        # All arguments are used
with_arguments { |x, y, z| puts x, y, z }  # z will be nil
```

Unused block arguments are discarded, and any extra parameters will be set to `nil`.

[This is specific to regular blocks and `Proc`s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-call) – `lambda`s will raise an error if given the wrong number of parameters. You can actually find out whether this is the case by calling [`Proc#lambda?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F)

Also, if you aren't going to store the block, it is cleaner to simply use `yield`:

```
def with_arguments
  yield 'foo', 'bar'
end
```

Comment: Also using the yield is faster.

Comment: Ah, once again I've been bitten by not including example code that perfectly matches my use case. This is certainly a helpful answer; but as it turns out I *am* mainly concerned with taking `lambda`s. Any thoughts on that limitation?

Comment: @MatheusMoreira: Nice update. I had quasi-settled (well, temporarily) on something similar in my own code: `def call_with_args(block, *args); block.call(*args.slice(0, block.arity)); end`

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions...

- always pass 2 parameters, even if one has to be nil
- just pass one array, which may have more or fewer elements. This kind of gives you the best of both worlds: because of the way multiple assignment works, you can leave out or supply extra block parameters with no warnings

Answer (score 0):

```
def bar(&block)
    puts 'In bar'
    block.call(1) if block
    puts 'Back in bar'
    block.call(1,2) if block
end

1.9.3p392 :043 > bar do |*b| puts b.length end
In bar
1
Back in bar
2
```